# changing time axis values of netcdf4 file using R

Tags: r, netcdf4, ncdf4

I'm tried to change time axis of given netcdf4 file with given .csv table, like pasting all contents of table into the netcdf4 file. however, every method I took using R with ncdf4 or python cdo failed so far. and ncvar_put command dosen't seems to be working.

as of R, I have tried such a thing.

```
>library(ncdf4)

>nc_data<-nc_open('/home/vboxuser/netcdf4.nc')

#original time axis
> time<-ncvar_get(nc_data, "time")
> print(time)
 [1] 1449619200 1449622800 1449626400 1449630000 1449633600 1449637200
 [7] 1449640800 1449644400 1449648000 1449651600 1449655200 1449658800
[13] 1449662400 1449666000 1449669600 1449673200 1449676800 1449680400
[19] 1449684000 1449687600 1449691200 1449694800 1449698400 1449702000
[25] 1449705600 1449709200 1449712800 1449716400 1449720000 1449723600
[31] 1449727200 1449730800 1449734400 1449738000 1449741600 1449745200
[37] 1449748800 1449752400 1449756000 1449759600 1449763200 1449766800
[43] 1449770400 1449774000 1449777600 1449781200 1449784800 1449788400
[49] 1449792000

#new time axis which is to be implemented
> time_n<-read.csv('/home/vboxuser/time.csv')
> print(time_n)
             
1  2014-10-01 00:00:00
...
49 2014-10-03 00:00:00

#pasting time axis to the said netcdf file.
> ncatt_put(nc_data,var, "time", time_n)
Error in ncatt_put(nc_data, var, "time", time_n) : 
  ncatt_put: the netcdf file has not been written to disk yet, or was not opened in write mode!

> ncvar_put(nc_data,"time", "time_n", verbose=TRUE)
[1] "ncvar_put: entering"
Error in ncvar_put(nc_data, "time", "time_n", verbose = TRUE) : 
  Error: called with a nc object that is NOT a writable netcdf file! Passed nc file name:  /home/vboxuser/netcdf4.nc
```